# active record relations – who needs it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-relations

Well, I`m confused about rails queries. For example:

```
Affiche belongs_to :place
Place has_many :affiches
```

We can do this now:

```
@affiches = Affiche.all( :joins => :place )
```

or

```
@affiches = Affiche.all( :include => :place )
```

and we will get a lot of extra SELECTs, if there are many affiches:

```
Place Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Place Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Place Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = 444 LIMIT 1
Place Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = 222 LIMIT 1
...and so on...
```

And (sic!) with `:joins` used every `SELECT` is doubled!

Technically we cloud just write like this:

```
@affiches = Affiche.all( )
```

and the result is totally the same! (Because we have relations declared). The wayout of keeping all data in one query is removing the relations and writing a big string with "LEFT OUTER JOIN", but still there is a problem of grouping data in multy-dimentional array and a problem of similar column names, such as `id`.

What is done wrong? Or what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Well, i have that string `Place Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE ("places"."id" IN (3,444,222,57,663,32,154,20))` and a list of selects one by one `id`. Strange, but I get these separate selects when I`m doing this in `each` scope:

```
 <%= link_to a.place.name, **a.place**( :id => a.place.friendly_id ) %>
```

the marked `a.place` is the spot, that produces these extra queries.

UPDATE 2:

And let me do some math. In console we have:

```
 Affiche Load (1.8ms)  SELECT affiches.*, places.name FROM "affiches" LEFT OUTER JOIN "places" ON "places"."id" = "affiches"."place_id" ORDER BY affiches.event_date DESC
 <VS>
 Affiche Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "affiches".* FROM "affiches"
 Place Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE ("places"."id" IN (3,444,222,57,663,32,154,20))
```

Comes out: 1.8ms versus 4.1ms, pretty much, confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is really strange here because `:include` option is intended to gather `place_id` attribute from every affiche and then fetch all places at once using select query like this:

```
select * from places where id in (3, 444, 222)
```

You can check that in rails console. Just start it and run that snippet:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new STDOUT
Affiche.all :include => :place
```

You might be incidentally fetching affiches without actually including places somewhere in your code and than calling place for every affiche making rails to perform separate query for every one of them.

Comment: As far as i know this operation with `in` is heavy to maintain too, but it\`s obviously faster than the multiple selects one by one. The last thing is to get it done that way.
But again it\`s almost two times slower than a single SELECT with LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: I think for most cases one more query for associations is ok. `Affiche.all :joins => :place` will perform join but won't actually select anything from places table. If you add to that custom `:select => 'places.*, affiches.*'` you'll get in the result an array of objects that will have attributes from both tables but it's awkward as you won't actually have objects of either of you models and if I remember correctly these objects will be read-only.

Comment: that\`s right, but `places.id` and `affiches.id` will surely conflict

Comment: And anyway if there is no problem of fetching, there is a problem of performance (see the second update)

Comment: Sure. Unless you have some outstanding rpm in your app or data amounts that are huge enough for rolling out custom solutions for querying data from DB I'd suggest using `:include` for such cases. I believe two queries (actually 1 + n if you fetch smth with n associations included) is the best what rails can provide in that situation.

Comment: I might panic too early, because i think that the problem may be, so let it be this way – include.
But what\`s wrong in the first update? How to avoid extra queries in view?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. As I understand every place have a friendly place. Is it right? And why are you fetching it through `a.place`?

Comment: Well, I did it, the hash in brakets was unneded. I did a lot of noise =) Thank you!

Comment: Huh, I didn't get it. How does this piece look now?

Comment: just that: `link_to a.place.name, a.place( )`